# Use review form in Product description page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2

rather then using magento2  form like this in product description page

```
<block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
</block>
```

Can I use other way ? as its creating some issues on page.